# How to deploy a React SSR application to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, server-side-rendering

I have simple running react Server Side App .

[**GitHub Link**](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/React-SSR) for the repo, in the local env i have a build script that runs using npm start which starts the client and server  builds and then i have a watcher which listen's to changes in file. This set up works really well locally.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:*",
    "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec \"node build/bundle.js\"",
    "dev:build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch",
    "dev:build-client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js --watch"
  },
```

I tried to deploy these changes as a prod app to [**heroku here**](https://react-universal.herokuapp.com/) for some odd reason it never works and returns 503 . I have not added any changes to the build scripts in the package.json and tried deploying as is.

I thought it should work as the [build log](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/react-universal/activity/builds/69db54e4-49e0-4ce6-9c16-061d3bf86f41) dosent give any errors on heroku but while trying to access the app it shows error and asks me to check app log but i am not using heroku cli and not planning on using it , and

> thinking of auto deployment from github.

I am quite new to script/ largely build scripts trying to learn more on them.

> How can we make sure this small React SSR git repo deploys and i am
>   able to access the home page .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not using heroku cli and not planning on using it

You should and I really recommend, as it's the best way to see errors that occurs after the build, why your app crashed and see the full logs. Even though you can see the logs from your heroku dashbord (More -> View logs), this only gives you the tail of the logs.

> How can we make sure this small React SSR git repo deploys and i am able to access the home page.

Make sure the server is listening on the right [port](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/React-SSR/blob/d7d5e9ccf7802d95f43cabf7a2419229190f552c/src/index.js#L41)
by using `process.env.PORT` as heroku expose a dynamic port.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening on Port ' + port);
})
```

On heroku the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to`production` by default, 
which means heroku will prune the`devDependencies` after the build, 
but in your case, you still need these dependencies to start your app with webpack.

You can fix this in two ways :

1. Customize your build process by adding a `build` script:

   From your github
   [repo](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/React-SSR/blob/master/package.json#L7)
   :

   ```
   "start": "webpack --config webpack.client.js; webpack --config webpack.server.js; node build/bundle.js"
   ```

   to

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "start": "node build/bundle.js",
       "build": "webpack --config webpack.client.js & webpack --config webpack.server.js",
       "build:start": "webpack --config webpack.client.js && webpack --config webpack.server.js && node build/bundle.js",
   }
   ```
2. Set the `NODE_ENV` to any other value to skip pruning your
   `devDependencies`

   ```
   heroku config:set NODE_ENV=development //(Another reason to use the CLI)
   ```

Check this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation) for more details

Comment: thanks a lot , I am still not keen on using the CLI as i am not  worried a lot about some of the intricate connections, but i get your point and appreciate the details pointed out. 
Just for someone worried about setting config they can go to  https://dashboard-classic.heroku.com/apps/{your-app-name}/settings and set config vars.

I will also appreciate if you could add some of the details of where we get info on these will be the scripts and order heroku looks at . will be a great read for me and some one looking out for a similar answer

Comment: My answer is mainly based on the link (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation) provided in the answer.
Here are also some useful links https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up and 
https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error